# Responsive box elements when browser window gets narrower with proper min max rules

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I am trying to align some box elements with the following design where each box element should have max-width:300px size in normal view.
[image]

And, when we start narrowing the browser from the right, the box elements should stay in the same lines until the individual box width becomes min-width:200px. And, When the box elements size reaches to min-width:200px the elements from the right should move to the next lines.
I was able to align the items properly with max-width:300px initially but the problems happens when I try to re-size the browser and trying to achieve the min-width:200px behavior. Seems like, my box elements never re-sized to 200px when I just start re-sizing the browser already. For example:in the following image why it's like that?
[image]

What I am trying to do is that:

1. The box elements should stay with max-width:300px
2. When re-sizing the browser the box elements should stay in the same line and shrink the box elements till 200px and after that moves the elements to the next line.

I have been now trying that for couple of hours but couldn't solve it.Does anybody can help me with this problems or guide me how can I achieve this responsive behavior. Thanks in Advance.
Here is the code that I have tried so far:

```
.box-item{
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #C2C7CF;
  max-width:300px;
  min-width:200px;
  flex:300px;
  height:56px;
  margin-left:32px;
  margin-right:32px;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;}
```

Here is the html:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">
   <div class="header">
    <p>One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
      <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
            <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
      <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
            <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
      <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
            <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
      <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
            <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
      <div class="box-item">Num One Box</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle link for details: https://jsfiddle.net/p1L9enxz/13/

Comment: can you also share your html, preferably in a stack snippet? thanks!

Comment: Hey, I have edited my question with the html. Also, the jsfiddle link I have provided it contains both the html and css. Let me know if it is okay for you. Sorry, didn't familiar with stack snippet you have mentioned...

Comment: I have tried the code from your fiddle and the boxes don't seem to change from size 300px (tried on Edge, Chrome and Firefox on Windows10), what am I missing?

Comment: @AHaworth exactly this is the problem I am having, the boxes doesn't get re-sized until 200px and just move to next line ( without reaching to the min-width:200px)

Comment: Noticed that it only re-size the items to 200px when there are only one items visible at last...Guys, is there any luck with this?